# Integrating MetaMask with Flutter Mobile Application

Tags: flutter, blockchain, metamask, wallet-connect, web3dart

I want to add feature in my mobile app to send ether from one address to another address and for this I need to integrate metamask with my flutter mobile application. What package can I use for this purpose? I want to send ether through metamask but using UI of my application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I implemented this in my app. Here's the code. Hope this helps
I have used the [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) package to open the wallet from where the user can connect their wallet to the app and [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open the wallet

```
Future<void> connectWallet() async {
    final connector = WalletConnect(
      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
        name: 'any name',
        description: 'any description',
        url: 'any url',
        icons: [
          'logo url'
        ],
      ),
    );

    // Subscribe to events
    connector.on('connect', (session) {
      debugPrint("connect: " + session.toString());

      address = sessionStatus?.accounts[0];
      chainId = sessionStatus?.chainId;

      debugPrint("Address: " + address!);
      debugPrint("Chain Id: " + chainId.toString());
    });

    connector.on('session_request', (payload) {
      debugPrint("session request: " + payload.toString());
    });

    connector.on('disconnect', (session) {
      debugPrint("disconnect: " + session.toString());
    });

    // Create a new session
    if (!connector.connected) {
      sessionStatus = await connector.createSession(
        chainId: 137, //pass the chain id of a network. 137 is Polygon
        onDisplayUri: (uri) {
          AppMehtods.openUrl(uri); //call the launchUrl(uri) method
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've implemented this but this is just for connecting to wallet and getting accounts. How can I do transactions? For example transfering usdt from wallet to another wallet address. I see everywhere people use web3dart but it is for interacting with contract! I just need to do a simple transfer why this should be so ridiculuosly hard to achieve in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

We are actively maintaining a flutter template for creating web3 mobile apps: https://github.com/Nuxify/Sophon

The template uses `walletconnect_dart` and `web3_dart` and also got an example  when connecting, reading, and writing to a Goerli smart contract.

Comment: I already connected to Metamask and got the accounts! How to do transfer usdt from wallet to another wallet? I don't want to interact with smart contract and put private key inside code. I want user accept transaction through Metamask.

Comment: HI there. I installed the Sample app from the playstore and metamask login is not working

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, there is web3dart that works for mobile app

https://github.com/simolus3/web3dart

In react, there is moralis

https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Metamask supports [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.com/) protocol so you can use `walletconnect_dart` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) to connect your app to Metamask wallet and then use the same package to sign/send transactions signed by Metamask.

Comment: Can you share how to transfer and sign with metamask in android app! using this package. I can connect to wallet but have problem transfering USDT in BNB chain.

Comment: You have to use `provider` from `walletconnect_dart`. Have a look at the example app either for `walletconnect_dart` package or for Ethereum example you can check out my package `walletconnect_qrcode_modal_dart`.